# Sklearn multiple features (multiple independent variables, on which the result y depends)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Here is my code:

```
X = np.array([[1, 2, 4],[2, 3, 9]]).T    
print(X)
y = np.array([1, 4, 16])
X_poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2).fit_transform(X)
print(X_poly)
model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept = False)
model.fit(X_poly,y)
print('Coefficients: \n', model.coef_)
print('Others: \n', model.intercept_)
```

Please, the generated model has the form of y=axx+b*z+c that's it ?

please, how can i differenciate between coefficient of each variable (x and z) ?

Comment: `model.coef_` generated 6 coefficients, x, z, x^2, z^2, xy, and intercept `c`.  You can see the powers by saving the `PolynomialFeatures`: `feats = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2); X_poly = feats.fit_transform(X)`. Then, you can finds the different powers by `feats.powers_`.

Comment: @GergesDib   Coefficients: 
 [-0.10133796  0.1456888  -0.01660059  0.54831516  0.45019822 -0.11496531]  (x= -0.10133796  ? an z= 0.1456888 ?

Comment: And please, how can i predict  (x=3, z= 3)    ---  > X_predict = np.array([[3,3]])
print(model.predict(X_predict))   ?

Comment: Check `feats.powers_`, and find the index of element which is (0,1) and than will be `z` and the index of (1, 0) will be `x`. Predict: `model.predict(feats.transform(X_predict))`.

Comment: You can check the examples: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_polynomial_interpolation.html

Comment: to check feats.powers, i have to use this code : coef_dict = {}
for coef, feat in zip(model.coef_,model.feats.powers_):
    coef_dict[feat] = coef      ?